# Is there a policy for DNS look-up in Apigee?

Tags: dns, apigee

Is there a policy that enables DNS look-up in Apigee? I have gone through the docs and tutorials and have not come across a solution.

Comment: any reason to need a policy for only a DNS lookup?

Comment: The use case is this: there is a callout in JavaScript from one API Proxy to another API Proxy that has been configured for a service. Based on the response (which contains a URL), processing is done and the target.url in the first API Proxy is overwritten to route the call to the correct host. In case there is a failure, a DNS look-up is needed to obtain the IP of the target endpoint that the second API Proxy reaches and this will be used to rewrite the target.url in the first one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do a callout to statdns.com and get a JSON payload back:

```
http://api.statdns.com/{domain name}/a
```

For example:

```
http://api.statdns.com/apigee.com/a

{
"question": [
    {
        "name": "apigee.com.",
        "type": "A",
        "class": "IN"
    }
],
"answer": [
    {
        "name": "apigee.com.",
        "type": "A",
        "class": "IN",
        "ttl": 60,
        "rdlength": 4,
        "rdata": "184.72.221.111"
    }
],
"authority": [
    {
        "name": "apigee.com.",
        "type": "NS",
        "class": "IN",
        "ttl": 86400,
        "rdlength": 20,
        "rdata": "ns3.p25.dynect.net."
    },
    {
        "name": "apigee.com.",
        "type": "NS",
        "class": "IN",
        "ttl": 86400,
        "rdlength": 6,
        "rdata": "ns4.p25.dynect.net."
    },
    {
        "name": "apigee.com.",
        "type": "NS",
        "class": "IN",
        "ttl": 86400,
        "rdlength": 6,
        "rdata": "ns1.p25.dynect.net."
    },
    {
        "name": "apigee.com.",
        "type": "NS",
        "class": "IN",
        "ttl": 86400,
        "rdlength": 6,
        "rdata": "ns2.p25.dynect.net."
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There is not a policy to simply execute a DNS lookup.  In the paid version of Apigee this could be built with a simple JavaCallout.

Comment: Please could you point me to an example of how this can be done? I have access to the paid version of Apigee.

Comment: depends on if you need to point to a specific DNS server.  If any DNS server will work for your purpose you can use Michael B.'s example below with a public DNS API.  In java and not needing to specify a nameserver, you can use the InetAddress class to do a lookup using the nameserver(s) that Apigee is configured to use. -- http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/InetAddress.html#getByName(java.lang.String)